# How to configure pip to install packages for python 2.x and python 3.x separately

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I am running Windows x64 bit.

I downloaded the **Pyro4** package via `pip install Pyro4`. It downloaded the packages successfully and they are all present in my `"C:\Python34\Scripts"` folder as I've kept **Python3.4** as default.

Now when I went to the that `"C:\Python27\Scripts"` folder, the **Pyro4** package is not to be found. This is as expected, but I would like to work on both Python **2.7** and **3.4** as Pyro4 is compatible in both.

How do I change my pip command to download the package to Python 2.7's installation scripts directory?

Comment: Do you have a pip script in your Python 2.7 directory, e.g. `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe`? If so, you can run that pip directly, e.g. `C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install Pyro4`, and it will install the package for 2.7.

Comment: I renamed version "pip.exe" python 2 to "pip2.7.exe" so... `pip2.7 install Pyro4` and the same with "python2.exe" can then start both on the prompt command without changing environment path.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you so much, it worked perfectly.
--Javier The problem with your method is I already have pip2.7.exe in that folder and it renames to pip2.7(2).exe, I used an installer from [activestate](http://www.activestate.com) for my python repositories maybe that is different from  the original python installer. Moreover, it says **Windows does not recognize pip2.7 as a command**.

Comment: @JavierClavero Although my 'pip2' or 'pip2.7' commands don't work my 'pip' and 'pip3' commands work fine. The problem is the commands 'pip -V' and 'pip3 -V' both point to "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages" where as it would be extremely convenient if pip pointed to "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a new environment variable:

1. Go to your system properties
2. Under Advanced tab click Environment Variables...
3. Under System variables section click New...
4. Variable name: (whatever you can remember for example p27s)
5. Variable value: your python 2.7 scripts folder ("C:\Python27\Scripts\")

From now on whenever you want to install a package for python 2.7 you can do it this way: %your_variable_name%pip install package_name

For example: C:>%p27s%pip install Pyro4

This way you can install any package for python 2.7 and use default pip for python 3.4

Comment: Thank you, this also works. But the simplest solution was just to add the path to your python2.7 files. As given by Alasdair in one of the comments

Answer (score 0):

You will need to go to your environment variables in the control panel and change the path from C:\Python34\Scripts to C:\Python27\Scripts. After that change, when you type 'python' in the command prompt it will be using Python 2.7. Next, install pip like you initially did.

Comment: Seems like an interesting method. Could you maybe help me out with the exact steps, as i have never changed environment variables before.
I've navigated to control panel ---> Edit environment variables for your account. 
What next?

Comment: If you are looking at the environment variables window => Look at the list of variables under "System Variables" and double-click on the 'PATH' variable.
1. Look for the path with "C:/Python34/" and change it to "C/Python27" 2. Change "C:/Python34/Scripts" to "C:/Python27/Scripts"

Comment: This probably shifts the pip command permanently to python2.7(until I undo it), this is not what I required. Making a variable with a custom name proved to be much more useful.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly what you're asking, but you could check out Anaconda which allows you switch python environments really easily.

https://www.continuum.io/downloads

*Edit*
Just to clarify

if you were to use this method, you can have named environments say python27 and python34

then you can just:

```
activate python27
pip install module

activate python34
pip install module
```

and it will install them to both environments.